# How to build + run cordova app in 1 step on Mac OS X?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova

I use Cordova/PhoneGap to create an iOS app. During development, I do changes to HTML/CSS/JS files in `www` folder and thus have to rebuild regularly. I usually do this on my Mac:

1. In terminal, I type: `cordova prepare`
2. I press `CMD` + `tab` to switch to Xcode
3. I hit `CMD` + 'R' to run the app on my attached iPhone

This works but it's a little annoying to repeat these steps all the time. Is there a way to speed this up, e.g. by creating a shell script that automagically does all these steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution for me. First, I installed `ios-deploy` via npm:

```
$ npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true
```

Then I simply run this for iOS for example:

```
$ cordova run ios --device
```

The `run` command will internally automatically call `prepare` and thus copy the content of `www` and then launch the app on the device.

Comment: cordova run executes prepare internally, so you don't need the prepare line. BTW, why did you downvote my answer? you found a better option, but mine isn't bad, and you didn't think it was bad if you accepted it some time ago. And this is the standart way of running apps, my answer is faster than yours, running from Xcode is way faster than using the CLI.

Comment: @jcesarmobile I never got it to work properly using your solution. That's why I downvoted.

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thanks for the hint on `run` calling `prepare` internally. I included that to my answer.

Comment: It's ok to unaccept because you found a solution that suits you better, but downvote becase you weren't able to do a simple task as moving a build script...

Comment: @jcesarmobile I was able to move the script but that didn't solve the problem. Only because your solution works for you it doesn't necessarily mean that it also works for others.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, on xcode go to "Build Phases", press the + button and select "New Run Script Phase".

Move it to be over the "Copy www directory"

And use this code:

```
cordova prepare ios
```

EDIT:
Is for some reason you can't move the new script over the "Copy www directory" one, I've found another way that will work.

Just open the "Copy www directory" (it's a build script too) and add the `cordova prepare ios` before the existing code

Comment: Are you sure? Shouldn't `cordova prepare` be called from cordova project folder root? If I just run `cordova prepare` from the xcode project, wouldn't that be the wrong path `platforms/ios`? Also, how do I "move the run script to be over "copy www directory""? Drag and drop doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, you can run cordova prepare form any folder inside your project, just check it.

Comment: To move the run script, first fold it, when it's folded, drag and drop will work

Comment: But did you move the run scrip over the copy www?

Comment: Here, see for yourself: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aj9eil6cxix0zsu/xcode_cordova_prepare.mov?dl=0

Comment: change the screen and try again, somethimes it get stuck and the drang&drop stop working

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work. Even XCode restart doesn't help. From the "feel" of d&d it seems like those items cannot be moved at all.

Comment: Don't move it left or right, just up, it seems that it's not working very well with xcode 7, but I assure you it can be moved

Comment: I just noticed: If I add `cordova prepare` before `cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.sh` I always get "Build canceled" :-(

Comment: try a few times, it got canceled for me the first time, but worked after a while

Comment: I did but sometimes it works but very often it doesn't. I think the script needs to wait a bit after `cordova prepare` until XCode is done preparing the new code copied in. I have the same problem if I manually do the process and hit `CMD + R` to quickly. So, I tried `sleep 5s` after `cordova prepare` in the script but that didn't work :-(

Comment: Then you should keep trying to create the separate build script and put it on top of the copy www one, I never had problems with that